# AutoMapper and MEF - How to get AutoMapper to implement specific Type when specifying only Interface

Tags: dependency-injection, automapper, mef

I am using AutoMapper to automatically map properties between entities that exist within different levels of my app.

All has been well, until I tried to introduce a new calculated property value in a business entity, with properties being auto-mapped from a data entity: The new calculated property value in the destination business entity is returning null every time.

I am using MEF for dependency injection, and am therefore specifying Interfaces for the source and destination types when using AutoMapper.

I think what is happening is that AutoMapper is creating a simple implementation of the destination class with the specified Interface (which would therefore not have the implementation code for the calculated property, thereby return null, which is what I am seeing), instead of the appropriate destination class being created by MEF according to the MEF Export definitions for the specified destination interface.

I am not at all sure how to proceed.

**Defining the Data Entity**

My data entity interface:

```
public interface IMyDataEntity
{
    string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
}
```

The implementation of the data entity interface, also defining the association between interface/implementation to be used by MEF:

```
[Export(typeof(IMyDataEntity))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class MyDataEntity: IMyDataEntity
{
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
}
```

**Defining the Business Entity**

My business entity interface:

```
public interface IMyBusinessEntity
{
    string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    string MyCalculatedProperty1 { get; }
}
```

The implementation of the business entity interface, also defining the association between interface/implementation to be used by MEF:

```
[Export(typeof(IMyBusinessEntity))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
public class MyBusinessEntity: IMyBusinessEntity
{
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string MyCalculatedProperty1 { 
        get{ return "Test"; }
    }
}
```

**Mapping with AutoMapper**

Trying to map from the Data Entity to the Business Entity:

```
IMyBusinessEntity myBusinessEntity 
= Mapper.Map<IMyDataEntity, IMyBusinessEntity>(myDataEntity,
            opts => opts.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true);
```

**The Issue**

myBusinessEntity.MyCalculatedProperty1 returns null.

Comment: reason you not getting the calculated values is because you don't have setter in  this "string MyCalculatedProperty1 { get; }"

Comment: Why would I need a setter for a calculated property?

Comment: i thought calculated value is from IMyDataEntity my bad. but "Mapper.Map<IMyDataEntity, IMyBusinessEntity>" this will not work for you beacuse IMyBusinessEntity is an interface and your calculated property is of concert class "MyBusinessEntity". You have to change your mapping.
in create map to concrete class and then map with concrete class
Mapper.CreateMap<IMyDataEntity, MyBusinessEntity> and then 
Mapper.Map<IMyDataEntity, MyBusinessEntity>